# Dealing with duplicate arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a scanner project I'm developing where a class reads in a txt file created by scanner and queries the database to display "bundles" scanner by a scanner per room. However now I have some rooms which duplicate the results. The results from the query are stop in arrays per day and manipulate. What i want to do is to display unique bundles and remove duplicates leaving the earliest entry. Below is my index page. Any tips advise would be much appreciated.

```
         <?php
// First of all initialise the user and check for permissions
require_once "/var/www/users/user.php";
$user = new CHUser(13);

// Initialise the template
require_once "/var/www/template/template.php";
$template = new CHTemplate();

// Initialise the scanner class
require_once "/var/www/Scanners/scanners.php";
$scanner = new CHScanners();

$_GET['date'] = date("Y-m-d", $scanner->GetPreviousMonday(strtotime($_GET['date'])));
$weeklyTotal = 0;

$content = "<h1>" . $scanner->GetRoomName($_GET['room']) . " Information</h1>
<form action='room.php' method='get'>
    Enter date: <input type='text' name='date' /><input type='submit' /><input type='hidden' name='room' value='" . $_GET['room'] ."' />
</form>
<table width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td style='vertical-align: top;'>
            <table width='100%'>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan='2'>Monday</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Bundle #</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                </tr>";

            $result = $scanner- 
              >ListRoomTotals($_GET['room'],$_GET['date']);
    $total = 0;

    foreach($result as $x) {
    $content .= "<tr>
        <td>" . $x[0] . "</td>
        <td>" . $x[1] . "</td>
    </tr>";
    $total += $x[1];
    }
    $weeklyTotal += $total;
           $content .= "<tr><td>Total Pairage:</td><td>".$total."                      
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Total Dozens:</td><td>".number_format($total/12,1)."</td></tr></table>
      </td> 

        <td style='vertical-align: top;'>
            <table width='100%'>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan='2'>Tuesday</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Bundle #</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                </tr>";
            $date = date("Y-m-d",(strtotime($_GET['date']) + 86400));
            $result = $scanner->ListRoomTotals($_GET['room'], $date);
            $total = 0;
            foreach($result as $x) {
                $content .= "<tr>
                    <td>" . $x[0] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $x[1] . "</td>
                </tr>";
                $total += $x[1];
            }
            $weeklyTotal += $total;
            $content .= "<tr><td>Total Pairage:</td><td>" . $total . "
                        </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Total Dozens:</td><td>" .  
                  number_format($total/12,1) . "</td></tr></table>
        </td>
        <td style='vertical-align: top;'>
            <table width='100%'>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan='2'>Wednesday</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Bundle #</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                </tr>";
            $date = date("Y-m-d",(strtotime($_GET['date']) +  
                           (86400*2)));
            $result = $scanner->ListRoomTotals($_GET['room'], $date);
            $total = 0;
            foreach($result as $x) {
                $content .= "<tr>
                    <td>" . $x[0] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $x[1] . "</td>
                </tr>";
                $total += $x[1];
            }
            $weeklyTotal += $total;
            $content .= "<tr><td>Total Pairage:</td><td>" . $total . "
                          </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Total Dozens:</td><td>" . 
                   number_format($total/12,1) . "</td></tr></table>
        </td>
        <td style='vertical-align: top;'>
            <table width='100%'>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan='2'>Thursday</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Bundle #</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                </tr>";
            $date = date("Y-m-d",(strtotime($_GET['date']) + 
                      (86400*3)));
            $result = $scanner->ListRoomTotals($_GET['room'], $date);
            $total = 0;
            foreach($result as $x) {
                $content .= "<tr>
                    <td>" . $x[0] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $x[1] . "</td>
                </tr>";
                $total += $x[1];
            }
            $weeklyTotal += $total;
            $content .= "<tr><td>Total Pairage:</td><td>" . $total . " 
                        </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Total Dozens:</td><td>" .  
                 number_format($total/12,1) . "</td></tr></table>
        </td>
        <td style='vertical-align: top;'>
            <table width='100%'>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan='2'>Friday</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Bundle #</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                </tr>";
            $date = date("Y-m-d",(strtotime($_GET['date']) + 
                       (86400*4)));
            $result = $scanner->ListRoomTotals($_GET['room'], $date);
            $total = 0;
            foreach($result as $x) {
                if($x[0] != "" and isset($x[0])) {
                    $content .= "<tr>
                        <td>" . $x[0] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $x[1] . "</td>
                    </tr>";
                    $total += $x[1];
                }
            }
            $weeklyTotal += $total;
            $content .= "<tr><td>Total Pairage:</td><td>" . $total . "
             </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Total Dozens:</td><td>" .  
             number_format($total/12,1) . "</td></tr></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>";

$options .= "Weekly Pairs: " . $weeklyTotal . "<br>
            Weekly Dozens: " . $weeklyTotal/12;

$template->SetTag("options", $options);
$template->SetTag("content", $content);
echo $template->Display();
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before appending do a [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) test.

Comment: looking at that it seems you have specifiy a value. I won't know the value, therefore this causes a problem.

Comment: Add the values to a single row temp array, then check the main array for duplicates.  If there is no duplicate then append, otherwise drop the temp array values on the floor.

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to implement the constraint in your query than to do it in PHP. Try using group by and using min on your date to get the room with the earliest entry. [Here is a relevant example on this site.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700806/mysql-select-min-for-all-time-but-only-return-if-between-dates)

If you wish to do it inside PHP, you would have to some filter. Set up a temp array to store the final results, and loop through all your results. If the room is not in the result array, add it. If it is, compare the date and use the earliest date.